my IDE (PyCharm) doesn't autocomplete functions of the 'cv2' import
As you understand, I was basically trying to make a motion detection system in Python using OpenCV with an alarm, which I will add later on.
My main problem is that the rectangle functions are not detected
or suggested during writing the code. As I am very new to this, I am unable to understand what's the cause of this error.
I was following a YouTube tutorial from a channel named Programming Hero.
I was not able to do much on my own to rectify my error.
The program works fine(Mmeaning my every smallest motion was contoured with the given color) when I write until line 12 and the last three lines are included, which is obviously needed.
But just after I write from lines 13-17 (REASON--So,that only bigger motions would be detected and surrounded by a rectangle), I run the program, but now, only my webcam opens,no rectangles are visible.
And also no, suggestions were being displayed while writing the rectangle functions.
Here is my program
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame1 = cam.read()
    ret, frame2 = cam.read()
    diff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # cv2.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    for c in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 5000:
            continue
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            cv2.rectangle(frame1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('My came', frame1)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('t'):
        break



Are you serious in expecting from people wanting to help you to type the code from the image to run it and provide a better version of it?

Hey and welcome to SO! Please improve your post by sticking to the guidelines of asking a question: 1- post code as code, not images. 2- include the image in question that you are trying to process. Bonus- desired results

i have uploaded the proper code ,pls have a look

you are asking multiple questions. the first is a problem with your IDE, PyCharm.

Hi there. I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Please read how to ask for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow. Does hitting <Ctrl>+<Space> help?



Cv2.rectangle function not detected by opencv,neither other functions
like cv2.boundingRect()

As you understand, I was basically trying to make a motion detection
system in python using opencv with an alarm which I will add later on.
My main problem is that the rectangle functions are not detected or
suggested during writing the code

You are not doing the right thing.
I tried to work around.
You need to separate frame1 and frame2
Reduced  this:
if cv2.contourArea(c) < 5000:

To:
if cv2.contourArea(c) < 50:

So, you can detect motion when a human is moving or not.
Snippet(modified):
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret1,frame1 = cap.read()
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray1, (21, 21), 0)
cv2.imshow('window',frame1)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret2, frame2 = cap.read()
    gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray2, (21, 21), 0)
    
    deltaframe = cv2.absdiff(gray1, gray2)
    cv2.imshow('delta', deltaframe)
    threshold = cv2.threshold(deltaframe, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    threshold = cv2.dilate(threshold,None)
    cv2.imshow('threshold',threshold)
    countour, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for i in countour:
        if cv2.contourArea(i) < 50:
            continue
 
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(i)
        cv2.rectangle(frame2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    
    cv2.imshow('window', frame2)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(20) == ord('q'):
      break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


@supra,thank you sir, but 50 is very little area,even leaves are getting detected

You can increase it slightly wherever it suits your needs.
